# Latex Template Gets Stuck when generating PDF

Tags: compiling, templates, debugging

I am working on my thesis and need to convert my paper to a different format. I'm new to using latex, only having started using it for this project, and am struggling to get the base version of this template working. No error occurs, but compilation appears to halt, judging by the fact that main.log log ceases to update after a certain point. The repository hasn't been updated in a while, so I am guessing that the setup may be outdated. I've tried removing some of the references to other sections, but that doesn't appear to make a difference. If someone could help me get this working, or point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

https://github.com/davidanastasiu/thesis_template-SJSU_CMPE

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  When you say that compilation seems to stop, does it return to a condition where you can resume typing, or does it just sit there?  If it just sits there, it may be in a loop.  Do you launch the compilation from within another process, such as an editor, or directly from the command line?  You can narrow down the place where it stops adding to the log by moving `\end{document}` earlier in the file, until you get a result that terminates cleanly.  (This is sometimes known as "divide and conquer".)  (continued)

Comment: (continued)  You might get some ideas from this article, which gives debugging suggestions: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-2/tb119beet.pdf